# error MSB3147, setup.bin missing on TeamCity server for clickOnce .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, teamcity, clickonce

I have moved a TeamCity server from an old 2008 R2 server to a 2012 R2 x64 server. I have installed a new build agent on the server and got almost everything up and running, except deployment of a Clickonce application, which is .Net 4.0 C#. It is failing with

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4513, 5): error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in ....

I have installed .

- .Net Framework 4.5 SDK
- .Net Framework 4.6.2 SDK
- Microsoft Build Tools 2013
- Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Window 7 (7.1)
- Windows Software Development Kit

Tried the described procedure here http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/02/msb3147-could-not-find-required-file-on.html but doesn't help.

Do anybody know how to get around this problem ?